# Comparison between $f(x)/f(y)$ and $x/y$ for a non-decreasing non-negative concave function when $0<x<y$

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a concave non-decreasing function, is it true that we always have $f(x)/f(y)> x/y$ when $0<x<y$? I look through the definition of concavity/convexity but didn't find suitable theorems for this. I have an intuition that this is true. For example, when $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, $f(x)/f(y)> x/y$ when $0<x<y$. Is this conclusion true in general?

---

Update: I update the strict inequality to be non-strict inequality. So is it true that $f(x)/f(y)\geq x/y$ when $0<x\leq y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
x = \alpha \, y = \alpha \, y + (1 - \alpha) \, 0.$$
Hence, by concavity
$$
f(x) \ge \alpha \, f(y) + (1-\alpha) \, f(0) \ge \frac{x}{y} \, f(y).$$

The same reasoning shows that you get a strict inequality for strictly concave functions.

Answer (score 1):

The strict inequality I think breaks it.  For example: consider $f(x)=x$.  Then $f(x)/f(y)=x/y$ for all $x$ and $y$.  This is also non-decreasing.  Also, using the definition that $f((1-\alpha)x+\alpha y)) \geq (1-\alpha)f(x)+\alpha f(y)$ for concavity, note that $f((1-\alpha)x+\alpha y))=(1-\alpha)x+\alpha y=(1-\alpha) f(x) + \alpha f(y)$.  So $f(x)=x$ is concave.

Comment: That's a good point, what about non-strict inequality (I think that's what I meant, sorry...)?  Otherwise, I might need to require the function to be strictly concave... I updated my question a to be non-strict ineqaulity